# Load iframe using jquery onclick, but it works only on jsfiddle

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, iframe

Why this code run correctly in jsbin.com and jsfiddle, but on my website not ? I have got url to jquery library, and no more ideas...Somebody can help? Please.

HTML : (just ID gonna be easier)

```
<a href="JDglMK9sgIQ" class="video">#1</a>
<a href="LpKyzSxVhk4" class="video">#2</a>

<div class="video-wrapper">
    <iframe id="youtube" width="560" height="315" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
</div>
```

jQuery :

```
$('a.video').click(function () {
    var id = $(this).attr('href');
    var src = '//www.youtube.com/embed/'+id;
    $("#youtube").attr('src', src);
    return false;
});
```

Comment: Have you checked using a web inspector like Chrome Developer Tools ?

Comment: Generate simple html project with this, and look on effect please. Something must be wrong...

Comment: Which browser you're using ?

Comment: Opera,Firefox, Chrome...everything is the same. But I have change a little this code and it's work on jsfiddle, codepen etc.

Comment: Have you tried wrapping your jQuery function in $(document).ready() function?

Comment: jQuery(function ($) {
   "use strict";
$("a.video").click(function () {
    var id = $("this").attr("href");
    var src = "//www.youtube.com/embed/" + id;
    $("#youtube").attr("src", src);
    return false;
});
  }(jQuery));

Comment: Derek, please answer how it should looks like maybe? please

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the jQuery is being loaded. You can add the cdn by adding this to the head section.

```
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

And you might need to wrap your function in `$(document).ready()` function.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('a.video').click(function () {
        var id = $(this).attr('href');
        var src = '//www.youtube.com/embed/'+id;
        $("#youtube").attr('src', src);
        return false;
    });
});
```

Hope that helps! Best of luck.